# MacBook Pro not booting beyond mounting Recovery HD

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

For some reason El Capitan doesn't boot. I've tried reinstalling from Recovery and nothing happened. The disk checked is ok.

I can use the cmd+s or Terminal. Here is the verbose boot:

[image]

Comment: A new one added. Sorry

Comment: Still bad quality.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your hard drive has been corrupted somehow.  Use Internet Recovery (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> while booting) to recover/restore your machine.

You do back ups, right?

More than likely, your drive has failed.  Based on what I was able to make out in the (blurry) picture, the error `BSD root: disk0s2, major 1, minor 2` is very similar to this post:

[OSX system and installation disk won't boot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100393/osx-system-and-installation-disk-wont-boot)

I have personally experienced (just last week, actually) a similar situation and it too was a HDD failure.

You can also try running this command from the command line to get the SMART Status of your drive:

`diskutil info disk0 | grep SMART`

If you get anything other than `Verified`, your drive is failing; it's time to replace.

Comment: No I don't :-(  . But why the disk utility says it's ok. ? I can also access  to the vol through command line

Comment: Are you accessing the normal partition or the recovery partition through Terminal?  I would bet you are accessing the recovery partition.  It would be more helpful if you post a clearer picture of your screen.

Comment: I forgot to ask...Which MBP (year and specs) do you have?